# Cannot read property 'path' of undefined node js multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

i am building a app that lets the user create a camp and than edit it.Recently i added the upload image feature it works fine with the create route but on the edit one it doesnt let the user leave it blank cause if that happens it give the undefined error.Do you have anyideas how i can fix this.I dont have much experience so any help would be welcomed.

This is the js code

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router({mergeParams:true});
var Campground = require("../models/campground");
var middleware=require("../middleware");
const multer = require('multer');


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        const now = new Date().toISOString(); const date = now.replace(/:/g, '-'); cb(null, date + file.originalname);
    }
});

  const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // reject a file
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
    }
  };

  const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
      fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
  });
//edit
router.get("/:id/edit",middleware.checkCampgroundOwnership, function(req,res){


            Campground.findById(req.params.id,function(err,foundCampground){



                      res.render("campgrounds/edit",{campground :foundCampground});


              });



});

router.put("/:id",upload.single('image'),middleware.checkCampgroundOwnership, function(req,res){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var image = req.file.path;
    var description = req.body.description;
    var price = req.body.price

    var upCampground = {price:price,name:name, image: image ,description:description};
    Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,upCampground,function(err,updatedCamp){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        }
        else{
            res.redirect("/campgrounds/"+req.params.id);
        }
    })
});
```

This is the ejs one

```
<%-include ('../partials/header') %>
<div class="container">

    <h1 style="text-align: center;"> Edit a <%= campground.name%></h1>
    <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
        <form action="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>?_method=PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="<%= campground.name%>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" value="<%= campground.price%> min="0.01" step="0.01"">
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" value="\<%= campground.image%>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" value="<%= campground.description %>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        <a href="/campgrounds">Go back</a>
        </div>



</div>
<%-include ('../partials/footer') %>
```

Comment: If it's possible for the user to leave the file blank, it means you need to make a conditional, to check if file exists, like if(req.file)

Comment: hello thank you now it works but the problem is that the image is blank now.I should use a else statment but i dont know how to get the exiting image before the edit to appear.if you could help me it would mean a lot.Thank you

Comment: Blank when? when the user doesn't upload one? Well this is for you to decide, what you want to store in the DB in this case

Comment: i want to store the same image that was

Comment: i found the solution thank you for the help.It was pretty obvious but idk why i was stuck.